# Select count from union table get error 'Column <name> is invalid in the ORDER BY...'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could you help to fix this?

[image]

Anyway, I don't want to group by, I want to search all.

I've search for hours, but found no answers for this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are counting all data. You haven't grouped by `not_id`

Comment: @Nebi: why do I need to group? I want to select all. Thank you. :?

Comment: You need a `Group by not_id` before the `order` statement

Comment: First of all, why you need order by as you need only the count?

Comment: You need no ORDER BY, since the query returns only one row.

Comment: @hungndv If you want to count all then just delete the `order by`-Statement. You will get the count of all in one row. If you want the count of all not_id's then you need to `group by` not_id

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you make `select not_id from notes where parent_not_id = 162` to union all with same rows?

If you specify `UNION ALL` it means you

> Incorporates all rows into the results. This includes duplicates.

So you if you got:

```
not_id
1
2
3
```

as a result of above query after running union you will get

```
not_id
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

That means after `COUNT` you will increase x2!

Next thing you are running COUNT with ORDER BY, why? COUNT will output 1 value in that case, so ORDER BY is meaningless in that query.

This query will do what you need:

```
select COUNT(not_id) as [cnt]
from notes 
where parent_not_id = 162
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why you need `order by` as you need only the count?

```
select count(*)
from (
  select not_id from notes where parent_not_id = 162
  union all
  select not_id from notes where parent_not_id = 162
) as T
```

If you need the count of distinct records, you need only `group by` and not `order by`.

```
select count(*)
    from (
      select not_id from notes where parent_not_id = 162
      union all
      select not_id from notes where parent_not_id = 162
    ) as T
   group by not_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group your data by `not_id`. Like so:

```
select count(*)
from (
  select not_id from notes where parent_not_id = 162
  union all
  select not_id from notes where parent_not_id = 162
) as T
group by not_id
order by not_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you count your data, you should have a group by clause in order to call the columns of the table,

Group it by `not_id`

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*)
from (
  select not_id from notes where parent_not_id = 162
  union all
  select not_id from notes where parent_not_id = 162
) as T
group by not_id
order by not_id
```

whenever you are using aggregate functions like count,max,sum,avg u need  to group by required columns

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of order by. You output will have just one row.

```
select count(*)
from (
  select not_id from notes where parent_not_id = 162
  union all
  select not_id from notes where parent_not_id = 162
) as T
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid of repeating the answers.  First of all, your main query is to get count which is going to give just one row.  And if I guess right,  then you need count by not_id for which you need to write query as

```
select count(*)
from (
  select not_id from notes where parent_not_id = 162
  union all
  select not_id from notes where parent_not_id = 162
) as T
group by T.not_id
order by T.not_id
```